# Google Workspace Admin SDK insert member always set type to "USER", how to resolve this?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-directory-api

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members

[https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members (click for image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJWwq.jpg)

It doesn't matter what I set "type" field to, in the request. It always sets it to "USER" in the response.

[This is the request (click for image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhpPi.jpg):

{
"email": "abcd@xyz.com",
"type": "EXTERNAL"
}

[This is the response (click for image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSojA.jpg):

{
"kind": "admin#directory#member",
"etag": ""9zPsLeP9ycRovNIzMe3UcREkFqt8n_JNHD4izBpxyt4/BY6DTvfyl-lbLpaBG_gjKb9l_X0"",
"id": "110243826665778914981",
"email": "abcd@xyz.com",
"role": "MEMBER",
"type": "USER",
"status": "ACTIVE"
}

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same, after unsuccessful attempts something I missed to notice in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members#Member) is the below:

> EXTERNAL: The member is a user or group from outside the domain. **(Not currently used)**

Basically, it does not matter whether the user is external/internal its type will always be set to 'User'.